# gpg uses temporary files instead of pipe

Tags: gpg

I have my `/root` mounted as read-only. 
I have a script that sends an encrypted email using `gpg`;
something like the following:

```
echo "hello" | gpg --no-verbose -e -a -r martin@example.com | mail martin@example.com
```

But I get an error:

```
gpg: failed to create temporary file `/root/.gnupg/.#dkflsfj': Read-only file system
```

How can I tell `gpg` not to use temporary files? 
I found an option `use-temp-files` in [the man page](https://manpages.org/gpg2):

> **`use-temp-files`**
>
>   On most Unix-like platforms,
>   GnuPG communicates with the keyserver helper program via pipes,
>   which is the most efficient method. 
>   This option forces GnuPG to use temporary files to communicate. 
>   On some platforms (such as Win32 and RISC OS), this option is always enabled.

I don't have this option enabled in my config. 
Apparently, it is set by default. 
Is there any way I could "negate" this option? 
The option `no-use-temp-files` does not seem to have any effect:

```
echo "asdf" | gpg --keyserver-options no-use-temp-files -e -a -r martin@example.com
```

I still get the same error: `` gpg: failed to create temporary file `/root/.gnupg/.#jkfjg': Read-only file system ``,
and if I say `--no-use-temp-files`,
I get an error: `gpg: Invalid option "--no-use-temp-files"`.

Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `--lock-never` option, which prevents `gpg` to attempt to lock the file.

Answer (score 2):

there is also this from k6 docs https://k6.io/docs/getting-started/installation/troubleshooting/#error-importing-k6s-gpg-key:

> This happens if it's the first time that the user runs gpg , so the directory /root/.gnupg/ doesn't exist yet. To create the directory, run sudo gpg -k and try to import the key again.

Comment: This doesn’t really seem to be relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The option can be disabled by adding prefix "no-"

> --keyserver-options name=value1
>
> > This is a space or comma delimited string that gives options for the keyserver.  Options can be prefixed with a `no-' to give the opposite meaning.

Comment: When I use `echo "hello" | gpg --no-use-temp-files --no-verbose -e -a -r martin@example.com` I get an error: `gpg: Invalid option "--no-use-temp-files"`

Comment: try `gpg --keyserver-options no-use-temp-files`

Comment: thanks, the option is recognized, but the problem with read-only filesystem persists: `gpg: failed to create temporary file `/root/.gnupg/.#jhsjd': Read-only file system`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to move your `/root/.gnupg` directory
to some suitably protected location on a filesystem that’s mounted read-write,
and then set `/root/.gnupg` to be a symbolic link to that location.